# Alignment of TextCtrl

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have newly set up Linux Mint in my computer and learning wxpython(just because I was bored of tkinter and needed some rest from the headaches i got from creating large applications on it). I learned about first command 'TextCtrl'. Every thing works except I have a bit problem. the code is simple.

```
panel = wx.Panel(self)
wx.TextCtrl(panel, position=(10, 10), size=(250,150)
```

the code works fine except when I run it the cursor and the text appears to be in the middle(like vertically middle). Searched the damn internet, never found a simple solution. any guesses how can i align in to top in a single line of code?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHQ3z.png)

Comment: Are you trying to make a multiline wx.TExtCtrl?

Comment: nope i'm just learning by watching a youtube video. so what he did was on windows and what i do is on the linux. although the codes are same, his is perfectly aligned(from top-left corner) but mines is like middle-left if you can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think wx.Python will automatically align the text to the center in the vertical direction. If you need a `wx.TextCtrl` that big, I guess you want a multiline `wx.TextCtrl`. This you can get with the `style` parameter:

```
wx.TextCtrl(panel, position=(10, 10), size=(250,150), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
```

Comment: @AndriousPrime Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. This helps to focus efforts on questions without an accepted answer.